# How can use VixVM_RunProgramInGuest vix library in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, vmware, vmware-tools

Hi I want use RunProgramInGuest function in python for running application in vm_ware workstation  but I can't Because I don't know the reference.
I want the simple code for the function thanks in advance.

Comment: any idea for the question ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find vix useful (can be found @ https://github.com/naim94a/vix or with `pip install vix`). This library wraps the VIX API in a safe way (RAII) and is object oriented.

```
import vix

host = vix.VixHost()
host.connect()

vm = host.open_vm("C:\\Virtual Machines\\MyVM.vmx")
vm.login(username="GuestUserName", password="GuestPassword")

vm.proc_run("C:\\GuestExecutable.exe")
```

Of course, if you would like to wrap the calls yourself the official documentation can be found here: https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/vix115_reference/index2.html

Comment: Please explain which parts of the URL you linked are relevant. Also read SO guidelines before posting.