# Python VIX API run in guest vmware workstation

Tags: python, vmware-workstation, vix

Dears

I'm new to VIX API, based on following code

[How can use VixVM_RunProgramInGuest vix library in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514341/how-can-use-vixvm-runprograminguest-vix-library-in-python)

```
import vix

host = vix.VixHost()

vm = host.open_vm("/home/Somebody/VM/Windows.vmx")
vm.login(username="User", password="Password")

vm.proc_run("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\WINWORD.EXE")
```

After executing the script, I found that the word application started under vmtoolsd service so it doesn't start in user space, it runs from  service vmtoolsd and I see interactive message is prompted. And MsWord Application's window does appear properly.

How can I execute word as the user which I loged in?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to vix's [documentation](https://naim94a.github.io/vix/vix.html#vix.VixVM.login):

`vm.login` has a parameter for interactive execution. You should add the `require_interactive=True` to the call.

```
import vix

host = vix.VixHost()

vm = host.open_vm("/home/Somebody/VM/Windows.vmx")
vm.login(username="User", password="Password", require_interactive=True)

vm.proc_run("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\WINWORD.EXE")
```